# PHP page returning black, Using PHP and the Google Docs API

Tags: php, google-api

I'm posting regarding this script from here: http://www.farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/ i have successfully set it up a while ago, but all of a sudden, it doesn't work anymore, i have no idea where to look for errors as page is returning black without errors.

Here's the code i use, i have placed zendgdata/library in public_html folder of my hosting and i have few parked domains on hosting.

Does anyone have a clue what it could be?

Thanks in advance...

```
<?php
// Zend library include path
set_include_path("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/ZendGdata-1.12.0/library");

include_once("Google_Spreadsheet.php");

$u = "username@gmail.com";
$p = "password";

$ss = new Google_Spreadsheet($u,$p);
$ss->useSpreadsheet("filename");
$ss->useWorksheet("sheetname");

@$a= addslashes($_POST['a']);
@$b= addslashes($_POST['b']);
@$c= addslashes($_POST['c']);
@$f= addslashes($_POST['f']);
@$g= addslashes($_POST['g']);
@$h= addslashes($_POST['h']);
@$j= addslashes($_POST['j']);

$id = "z" . md5(microtime(true));

$row = array
(
    "a" => $a
    , "b" => $b
    , "c" => $c
        , "f" => $f
            , "g" => $g
                , "h" => $h
                    , "j" => $j
);

if ($ss->addRow($row));
else echo "";

$row = array
(
    "a" => $a
);
?>
```

Comment: I have no idea why your page is displayed as **black**. If you mean *blank*, then that's probably because you don't have error reporting enabled. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script and refresh the page and see if it outputs any error messages.

Comment: Oh my... i have misspelled it. It is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I have, somehow, formatted my url wrong. It's fixed the issue.